# rust on steel post

Tags: structural-engineering

Is/will the rust on the steel post in the foreground a problem?
See the post in the background has no rust.
A primer was added and intumescent paint will also be added later.

[image]

Comment: The I beam with no rust looks like new construction. The square beam with rust looks like a temporary fence . I would guess the fence will come down after construction ?

Comment: they're both new construction

Comment: Grey is often hot zinc dipped. You can grind off and apply grey liquid zinc but not as good. Most plastic paints are hydroscopic so it will eventually rust. Epoxy paint is alittle better.

Answer (score 1):

In general, "no". But you need to read the material specification for the post whether it should be bare (untreated) steel or galvanized steel, which has the look of the posts on the back. Also, you shall read the specification for surface preparation and painting, if galvanization wasn't specified. Usually, the steel mill/supplier will apply the base coat to the bare steel, so it wouldn't be looking so rusty when fresh.

Answer (score 1):

The rust will prevent paint from sticking properly unless it is thoroughly removed. Then paint must be applied to the post to prevent it from rusting in future. any pinhole or scratch in the paint coating will cause rapid rusting at the pinhole and under the paint, which will then flake off. This is why posts for outdoor exposure are usually hot-dipped in zinc.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the differences are caused by cold rolled , hot rolled , and how long and what conditions they were stored at the mill and the job site. In any case it must be cleaned to get a satisfactory coating.